# How to add OR to a where statement when setting Rails instance variable?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How would I add "OR" to this where statement when setting my instance variable in a Rails controller?

`@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map {|u| u.id}).where("owner_id IS NOT NULL").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)`

I want to set @activities to records where owner_id is equal to either current_user.id or the current_user.followed_users. I tried adding `.where(owner_id: current_user.id)` but that seems to negate the entire query and I get no results at all. The query looked like this after I added to it:

`@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map {|u| u.id}).where(owner_id: current_user.id).where("owner_id IS NOT NULL").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)`

How can I add an OR condition so that I pull records where owner_id is either current_user or current_user.followed_users?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "owner_id is ... current_user.followed_users", given that the latter is presumably a multi-element relation or array? Do you mean "is included in"?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, yes that is an array and will be translated into `IN`

Comment: @BillyChan Actually, it's probably an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, right? :-)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, as `map` is method of Array, I think it will change this CollectionProxy and return Array.

Comment: @BillyChan I agree that `map` will _return_ an array, as implemented in `Enumerable`, but that doesn't mean that `followed_users` _is_ an array. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to include current_user's id in the array.

```
# Also use pluck instead of map
ids = current_user.followed_users.pluck(:id) << current_user.id
PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC")
  .where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: ids).page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't support "OR" directly in this context, so you either have to reconstruct your query to avoid it (as shown in [the answer from Billy Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208348/1008891)) or provide the SQL as an argument to the `where` as in:

```
.where("owner_type = 'User' and (owner_id = ? OR owner_id in (?))", current_user.id,
  current_user.followed_users.pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map(&:id)+[current_user.id]).page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
```

One line solution :)